# How do we update the Kernel for a Oracle Linux OS while leaving the OS Version same?

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, oracle-linux

I have tried to update the kernel for an Azure VM running Oracle Linux 7.2. I wanted to update the kernel version that was showing 3.10 and when I ran the yum update command, it upgraded all the packages that were in the yum repo and upgraded the OS to 7.5. I had to do a rollback but I want to update only the kernel to 4.10 and keep everything else the same.

Comment: Can you download kernel packages and install them separately?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update only kernel you should use command:

```
yum update kernel
```

Bear in mind that it might be to possible to update kernel to version 4.10 since Oracle Linux is based on RHEL, and in RHEL7 the kernel version is 3.10.

If you want to check available kernel versions you can use command:

```
yum list available 'kernel*'
```